# How to simplify MIPS ADD 1 / SLT / BNE into fewer Instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips, micro-optimization

How can these MIPS instructions be reduced to fewer instructions?

```
addi  $8, $3, 1
slt   $9, $2, $8
bne   $9, $0, End
```

Comment: Maybe  `sle   $9, $2, $3 ; bne   $9, $0, End`

Comment: Probably `<=` instead of `++` and `<`.  There is a pseudo-instruction `blt` or `ble` but that doesn't really count as fewer instructions.  There's also `bgez` as a real HW instruction, maybe  `sub` / `bgez` could also work like `sle` / `bne`.  Or maybe not, and `sle` is the more obvious one for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Simplify these MIPS Instructions?

```
slt $9, $3, $2
beq $9, $0, End
```

Here's one way to reason it out.  You want to do:

```
if ( $2 < $3+1 ) goto End;
```

We convert that to remove the addition:

```
if ( $2 <= $3 ) goto End;
```

But we don't have `<=` on MIPS, so, we *reverse the condition **and** negate it*.  This double negation cancels out so still represents the same logic.  This removes the equality component of the comparison:

```
if ( ! ( $2 > $3 ) ) goto End;
```

now, we swap the operands... since MIPS also doesn't have `>` :

```
if ( ! ( $3 < $2 ) ) goto End;
```

(NB: This swapping of the operands does not negate the condition: for this kind of swap we keep the equality component the same (here, absent) when flipping the operator; whereas in negation as in the preceding step, we *flip the operator and also change its equality component*.)

The good news is that we can perform this in only two instructions, *because the negation can be folded into the branch instruction* by using `beq` (branch on false) instead of `bne` (branch on true).

In fact, if you use the `ble` pseudo instruction, you'll get the same above two-instruction sequence.

```
ble $2, $3, End
```

---

As an aside, `sle` is a poor option, depending on your criteria.

MIPS doesn't have `sle` as an instruction, it is a pseudo instruction that does:

> `sle $9, $2, $3` generates:

```
slt $9, $3, $2    # generate the opposite condition
ori $1, $0, 0x1   # generate the constant 1
sub $9, $1, $9    # generate 1 - "the opposite condition"
```

As you can see it puts several additional instructions toward making the exact `1` vs. `0` answer we ought to get for `sle`, to which you'll still have to add a branch instruction, so that makes 4 instructions!  (And we could have branched on false after the initial instruction of that expansion.)  There also is no "reverse subtract immediate", so an R-Type subtract is used with a separately generated constant.

Comment: Does this transformation work even with the possibility signed wraparound?  (i.e. would it be safe for `addiu` as well as `addi`?)  I think not: `<= INT_MAX` is a lot different from `< INT_MIN`.  So maybe worth mentioning that `addi` faults on that wraparound and we're *not* replicating the behaviour for that input (because this version can't raise an integer overflow exception).

Comment: I checked, compilers don't do this optimization because it's not safe unless you rule out `y==INT_MAX`, or when signed overflow is UB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use a pseudoinstruction like `blt $9, $2, End` to write the SLT and BNEZ on one source line.  But I doubt that's what you mean; the rest of the answer is only concerned with reducing the number of hardware MIPS instructions.

---

Unless otherwise stated, an optimization is only safe / allowed if it gives the same behaviour for *every* possible input.  For optimizing asm -> asm, **you need to know which parts of the behaviour are desired and which are just implementation details** that don't need to be preserved.

In this case, I think we're meant to assume that creating `$8 = $3+1` is not part of the visible / desired behaviour.  I think the point is just to branch or fall-through using fewer than 3 instructions, regardless of what temporary we create or not.  (e.g. `subu $8, $2, $3` / `bgez` might be an option.)

---

**You can only optimize/simplify this if you change behaviour for the `$3 = INT_MAX` corner case**.  (Or if you have some guarantees about the possible ranges of your inputs).

In the original, MIPS **`addi` traps on signed overflow**.  (That's why it's normally never used; `addiu` wraps like you'd expect and is otherwise identical.)  **Raising this exception for `$3 = 0x7FFFFFFF` and not for any other case pretty much requires that you use `addi` with an immediate `1`.**  That's part of the behaviour of the original sequence and nothing in the question tells us we're allowed to relax that.

---

If you had used `addiu` to implement `jump if ($2 < $3+1)` with 2's complement wraparound, then `INT_MAX` is still a special case.  If `x <= 0x7FFFFFFF` is true for all x, but `x < -0x8000000` is false for all `x` (32-bit 2's complement, which is what MIPS `slt` implements).  `x < y+1` is equivalent to `x <= y`, but only if `y+1` doesn't wrap.

e.g. in C, signed integer overflow is UB, but unsigned wraps.  And the rules for converting unsigned to signed are well-defined as modulo-reducing in a way that means 2's complement machines (like MIPS) can just take the unsigned bit-pattern as signed, i.e. the cast is free and just a type-pun.

```
// C equivalent to asm using `addiu`.  C for MIPS uses 32-bit unsigned and 2's complement int
void foo_wrapping(int x, int y)
{
    unsigned tmp = y;
    tmp++;               // wraps without UB
    int wrapped_yp1 = tmp;
    // y+1 with 2's complement wraparound, without using -fwrapv

    if (! (x < wrapped_yp1))
        sink = 0;
}
```

GCC5.4 for MIPS compiles it as follows (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+sink%3B%0A%0A//+signed+overflow+is+UB%0Avoid+foo_nooverflow(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A++++if+(!!+(x+%3C+y%2B1))%0A++++++++sink+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//%23pragma+GCC+optimize(%22wrapv%22)++//+to+make+y%2B1+well-defined+for+y%3DINT_MAX%0Avoid+foo_wrapping(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A//++++if+(y+%3D%3D+0x7FFFFFFF)+__builtin_unreachable()%3B++//+uncomment+this+to+let+the+compiler+ignore+that+corner+case.++i.e.+promise+y!!%3DINT_MAX%0A%0A++++unsigned+tmp+%3D+y%3B%0A++++tmp%2B%2B%3B+++++++++++++++//+wraps+without+UB%0A++++int+wrapped_yp1+%3D+tmp%3B%0A++++//+y%2B1+with+2!'s+complement+wraparound,+without+using+-fwrapv%0A%0A++++if+(!!+(x+%3C+wrapped_yp1))%0A++++++++sink+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+foou(unsigned+x,+unsigned+y)+%7B%0A++++if+(!!(x+%3C+y%2B1))%0A++++++++sink+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:28.485792276986103,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fomit-frame-pointer+-target+mips+-march%3Dmips2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.515478063392926,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.99872965962098,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**).  Register numbers are different from your question, but the pattern is identical.  (add result on the right-hand side of SLT, then a BNEZ on that SLT result.)

(`add` vs. `addu` sort of happens to match up with C signed overflow being UB, unsigned just wrapping, but note that C compilers use `addu`/`addiu` even for signed addition because one thing UB is allowed to do is wrap.  C doesn't *require* it to be detected and crash, the whole point is that it allows the optimizer to assume it doesn't happen at all.)

```
# gcc5.4 -O3
foo_wrapping(int, int):
        addiu   $5,$5,1
        slt     $4,$4,$5
        bne     $4,$0,$L7
     ... a store that it conditionally jumps over, then jr $ra
```

clang9.0 also emits the same code.  Compilers not finding optimizations isn't proof that none are possible, but it's a nice check that my reasoning above is correct.

Using plain `y+1` and compiling with gcc or clang `-fwrapv` (to make signed overflow well-defined as 2's complement wraparound) also gives the same result.  And then using `if (y == 0x7FFFFFFF) __builtin_unreachable();` works correctly to promise the compiler that `y!=INT_MAX`, letting the compiler optimize.  Compilers miss in the version using unsigned.

---

If we exclude `INT_MAX` as a possible input (i.e. we don't care about the case where the original code trapped), then we can represent the operation in C as `x < y+1` for signed `int` vars.  In C, signed-overflow is Undefined Behaviour so optimizing compilers are allowed to assume that `y+1` doesn't overflow, and thus that `y!=INT_MAX`.

```
// This C is not equivalent to your asm.
// It doesn't trap on y==0x7FFFFFFF, and it doesn't necessarily wrap like addiu
int sink;
void foo_nooverflow(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y+1) {
        sink = 0;      // a store can't be done branchlessly
    }
}
```

```
## gcc5.4 -O3
foo_nooverflow(int, int):
        slt     $4,$5,$4
        beq     $4,$0,$L4
```

So gcc/clang transform the condition [as Erik Eidt's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177630/how-to-simplify-mips-add-1-slt-bne-into-fewer-instructions/58177801#58177801), comparing in the other order and swapping `bne` for `beq` as a way to implement `jump if ($2 <= $3)` because MIPS only has a limited selection of `sXX` instructions.

---

A version using `unsigned x, y` also has to `addiu` separately from the compare, and then uses a different compare instruction: `sltu`.  `slt` is a signed (2's complement) comparison.

The distinction is important when either input has its high bit set.